# how can i print object value in php

Tags: php, mysql

this is my php code:

```
    <?php 
    //Creating a connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("****","****","****","****");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $strcode = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "Select movie_image from map_table2 where movie_image = '".$strcode."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con ,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $array[] = $row;

    }
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

When I run the php, I get this data:

> [{"movie_image":"231320166"}]

But I want to get this data:

> 231320166

What code should I use?

Comment: You json encode it (but don't set the proper header), if you just want the data you can `echo $array[0]['movie_image'];`

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: @Qirel i try this code, but get noting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

with:

```
echo $array[0]['movie_image'];
```

Comment: yw, glad to help, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php

$json = '[{"movie_image":"231320166"}]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$image = $array[0]['movie_image'];
echo $image;
```

See it here https://3v4l.org/lrnL6